# Granting and denying access to some views in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Up to this point we have been granting and denying access to some views in the following way:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->deny('add','edit','index','view', 'delete', 'translate');
}
```

It worked perfectly, but now as requirements have changed, we need to do a conditional filter and give an appropriate message. It should take User's role, which can be get at $user['role'], and then depending on action it should grant/deny it with providing appropriate message.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You can always use ACL. [ACL CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,
user's role are **buyer** & **seller**.

Seller can perform the following action **add** , **update** & **delete** & Buyers can  perform the following action **view**, **translate**

```
        public function beforeFilter() {
          parent::beforeFilter();
          if($user['role'] == 'buyers') {
                $actions = array('view','translate');
          } else {
                $actions = array('add','update','delete');
          }
         $this->Auth->deny($actions);

    }
```

For more details go to flowing [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into ACL here is a short tutorial on ACL in cakephp

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1